# Detect class in a child div and add class in a other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i detect a special class in a child div and a when the specific class is found add a class into a other div?

Example:

```
 <ul class="m-a-ul">
    <li class="menu">
 </ul>
```

Now the specific class `collapsed` is added through an action:

```
 <ul class="m-a-ul">
    <li class="menu collapsed">
 </ul>
```

A script should now detect that a child of the `ul` `m-a-ul` got added a class named `collapsed`. Now the class `darken` should be added to a other div with the ID `content`:

```
<div id="content" class="darken">
...
</div>
```

And now, when the class `collapsed` disapears the class `darken` should also be removed

Ive tried this Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("#content").addClass("darken");
    });
});
</script>
```

That adds the class darken when a button is clicked. But that was the wrong solution. I need one that add the class only when a class is found in a specific div.

Comment: use `.hasClass()`

Comment: @guradio, sorry but i have no expierience in javascript

Comment: and `addClass()`

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219767/340760

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Are you asking how to detect _when_ the change happens, or how to determine the `collapsed` class is present, or how to apply the `darken` class?

Comment: What is adding the ``collapsed`` class?

Comment: bootstrap is adding the collapsed class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if(jQuery('.m-a-ul .menu').hasClass('collapsed')){
     jQuery('#content').addClass('darken');
   }else{
     jQuery('#content').removeClass('darken');
   }
```

Comment: Does not seem to work: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOVX5NZZKIKO

Comment: You must add javascript after html https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOVX8Z3FTP0I or add in jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // code in here })

Comment: I there any possibility to execute the script also after the page is already loaded? I mean when the class "collapsed" is added afterwords

Comment: So i think you need add it in a action https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOVXWTFKZLXQ